# Separating a jQuery range slider

Tags: jquery

I have a [jQuery slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range) the want to make in a two different slider, the sliders are with one value connected:

```
$("#voltage" ).slider({
    values: [<%= math.floor(val2 * 1000 / 11) / 100.0 %>, <%= (val2 / 10 - math.floor(val2)) / 100 %>],
    min: 0.00,
    max: 0.99,
    step: 0.01,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#voltage-amount").val((0.001 + (ui.val2[0] * 10) + ui.val2[1] / 10).toFixed(4))
    }
})
```

My question is how can I separate this slider in two thanks in advance?

Comment: Are you talking about simple slider of JUI? http://jqueryui.com/slider/

Comment: yes that the first slilder take care of val2[0] and the second on make  take the changes on val2[1]

Comment: yes making out of this range slider two simple sliders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply omit `min`/`max` values and use some function to calculate values:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#voltage1, #voltage2").slider({
    step: .1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $($(this).data('id')).val(ui.value);
      recalc();
    }
  });
});

function recalc() {
  $(".answer span").text(
    parseFloat($("#first").val()) + parseFloat($("#second").val())
  );
}
```

```css
#voltage1,
#voltage2 {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="val2[]" id="first" value="0"/>
<input type="text" name="val2[]" id="second" value="0"/>

<div id="voltage1" data-id="#first"></div>
<div id="voltage2" data-id="#second"></div>

<div class="answer">Answer: <span>0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for you answer, but how should I call the value now voltage1 or voltage2 or ansew span

Comment: @Engine If you want to get that value, you can either create input instead of span and use `.val(/* calculation */)` or get it by selecting `$(".answer span").text()`. Also, you can get that value directly to variable and do something with it.

Comment: s there a way tthat by calling "$voltage" on that'S both voltage1 and voltage2 , my problem is that I'm really new to HTML/js world and I'm working on the embedded project where the code depends on the variables name :\